# Deploy multiple web MVC projects with one FileSystem publish profile (to one location)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

Currently, we have this kind of hierarchy:

- Solution

  - MVC/Web: `Main_Web`
  - MVC/Web: `Sub_Module_Of_Main_Web`
  - Shared Libraries: `Utilities`, etc

`Main_Web` gets deployed to local.website.com and is a huge monolithic project. `Sub_Module_Of_Main_Web` is a new feature and we wanted to house its assets and logic in its own web project, with its own views and controllers living "outside" of the main project in Visual Studio.

We use one-click publishing and the profile setup is `FileSystem` as we publish to a local IIS instance.

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <WebPublishMethod>FileSystem</WebPublishMethod>
    <LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Test</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
    <LastUsedPlatform>Any CPU</LastUsedPlatform>
    <SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish />
    <LaunchSiteAfterPublish>True</LaunchSiteAfterPublish>
    <ExcludeApp_Data>True</ExcludeApp_Data>
    <publishUrl>http://local.website.com/</publishUrl>
    <DeleteExistingFiles>False</DeleteExistingFiles>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

We haven't tried web deploy, but I'm not sure web deploy is appropriate here.

From what I understand, the one-click publish only works for ONE web project at a time. Is there be a way to combine publishing so both "Web" projects get built and deployed to the same location?

**EDIT**

Ultimately, the final published website should have both project's assets and logic.

Deployed folder expectations:

- bin

  - `Main_Web.dll`
  - `Sub_Module_Of_Main_Web.dll`
- Content

  - `css`, `js`, etc of Main
  - Sub

    - `css`, `js`, etc of Sub
- Views

  - Main views
  - Sub views

Comment: explain a little bit more how you want to deploy the 'sub module' on IIS, would that be deployed in the sub folder of the main website. What is the current folder structure where you deploy both projects manually.

Comment: @AliAshraf I've updated the main post, hope that clarifies. Both web projects publish to the same iis folder, but the sub project has additional folders like `Content/Sub_Module/main.css` to prevent overwriting `Main`'s files.